# How do i reduce memory usage?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

What ways are there to reduce vram (GPU memory) usage in blender? I am rendering a scene and it's taking a lot of GPU memory. I have a 2GB card. What are some methods? i am pretty sure this has been asked before, but i didn't get the answer i needed.

Comment: now that you are becoming a regular in this site, keep in mind that there is a search box at the top. If you are not finding what you need it helps if you detail what you have tried so far.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 main things that'll take up video mem are gonna be:
how big are your **textures**, and how many **vertices** are in your scene.

Use the *decimate* modifier on your models effectively.
Try out scene *simplify*.  I'm certain you can look those up for more info.

[image: decimate]
[image: simplify]

Comment: I don't actually have any textures in my scene...just materials